# Struggling to parse through an array/list into my second function- this is specific to the Fibonacci sequence and currently half working

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

```
def fibArray(N):
    fibarray=[] 
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fibnum=0
    while find < N:
            fibnum = (num1+num2)
            num1 = num2
            num2 = fibnum
            find = (find+1)
            fibarray.append(int(fibnum))
    return(fibarray)

def fibwritefile(fibarray):
    for X in range(len(fibarray)):
        with open(f"fib-number-{fibarray[X]}.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(str(fibarray[X]))
            file.close()

fibarray=fibArray(7)
fibwritefile(fibarray)
```

The expectation is I should have 7 files- ranging from 1-7 and within each file the corresponding fibonnaic number (the fibarray=[] elements.)

what I get instead:

```
fib-number-3.txt           
fib-number-1.txt  fib-number-5.txt 
fib-number-2.txt  fib-number-8.txt
```

Is five files with the Fibonacci number as file name- and only 5 files- I have tried to print the index in the file name but it does not work?

Could I please get the solution as its driving me nuts!

Comment: please share for each file the expected content

Comment: Why do give `7` to get 5 values ? why start `find` at 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with input `7` you expect

- file `fib-number-1.txt` to contain `1`
- ...
- file `fib-number-7.txt` to contain `1 1 2 3 5 8 13` (on each line)

---

You need to use the indice for the filename, not the corresponding value in the array, then slice the array to have the first N values

```
def fibwritefile(fibarray):
    for i in range(1, len(fibarray) + 1):
        with open(f"fib-number-{i}.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write("\n".join(map(str, fibarray[:i])))
```

And your `fibArray` can be simplified much

```
def fibArray(size):
    fibarray = [1, 1]
    while len(fibarray) < size:
        fibarray.append(sum(fibarray[-2:]))
    return fibarray
```

Comment: @Razro- thanks for the update- but the file should only contain a single number rather than the whole array on each line.

Comment: @JonasNoori and contain which number, the n-th value ? just do `file.write(str(fibarray[i]))` so